# I'd like to change random username from Guest <random number> to <random word>

Tags: php, random

I'll try and explain it.

This code here:

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $random = rand(10000,99999);
    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest ".$random."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

This would return a random username of Guest 13245 or Guest 85247 etc.

What I want is it to return Guest Betty, or Guest Ghost, or Guest Goat, or Guest Teapot etc.

How would I edit the code to achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance for your help, I really appreciate it.

I tried this:

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $random = rand(10000,99999);
    $filename="words.txt";
    $words=file($filename);
    shuffle($words);
    $word=$words[o];
    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest ".$word."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

But it didn't work lol

Answered. For anyone else who wants this function:

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $names= array('Goat', 'Teapot', 'Fuzzyface');
            $random = rand(0,count($names)-1);
            $name= $names[$random];
    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest ".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

That did the trick :) Thanks to Adder.

Comment: You would have to have a database of random names, prolly

Answer (score 2):

You would need a dictionary to do that. You can provide an array with the words

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $dictionary = array(0 => 'Betty', 1 => 'Ghost');
    $max = count($dictionary) - 1;
    $random = rand(0, $max);
    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest".$random."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

expand the array as you like. Maybe there is an additional dictionary with random words you can download somewhere. Of course you will have to check just with your numbers if the name has been given to someone already to avoid duplicates.

What I would recommend is that you create double-words instead to maximise the amount of words. You can take a list like from here: http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-nouns.html
and make names that always consist of 2 worlds such as betty_ghost. You can also let the user chose a prefix such as "uncle", brother, mister etc - or attach a random number to the word. With these words you need to be aware in any case that some people might not like the words they get - and not use your service. So allow them to get a new one if they do not like it.

In the code above that you added with the words file you have to replace

```
$word=$words[o];
```

with

```
$random = rand(0,count($words) - 1);
$word = $words[$random];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a mysql table with random words in it. Then you could pick a row at random and use it as the username. E.g.

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $randomSql = "SELECT RANDOM_WORD FROM `random_word_table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;"
    $randomQuery = mysql_query($randomSql);
    $randomResult = mysql_fetch_row($randomQuery);        

    $sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest ".$randomResult['RANDOM_WORD']."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    setcookie($cookiePrefix.'guest', base64_encode($userid), time()+3600*24*365, "/");
}

return $userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$names= array('Ann', 'Betty', 'Charles');
$random = rand(0,count($names)-1);
$name= $names[$random];
$sql = ("insert into cometchat_guests (name,lastactivity) values ('Guest ".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".getTimeStamp()."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standalone function that would return a random user name to you. Of course you need to add more names to the pool to reduce the chance of colliding names.

```
<?php
function make_random_username() {
    $user_name_pool = array(
        'Ghost',
        'Goat',
        'Teapot'
    );
    $number = rand(0, count($user_name_pool) - 1);
    return 'Guest '.$user_name_pool[$number];
}
?>
```

If you don't want to make up a lot of user names, there's a [list of the most common english nouns](http://www.desiquintans.com/articles.php?page=nounlist) available.